# JDBC: Call external SQL Scripts, which declare a PL/SQL Package

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a SQL Script called setup which establishes some settings and then declares a PL/SQL package called salespack

setup.sql:

```
set verify off
set feedback off
set serveroutput on;
set linesize 200;
@Package/pack.sql
@Package/packbody.sql
```

I have a file called main.java, which tries to run the above SQL Script and then make a call to the package, but this does not seem to work. How can I use jdbc to call the SQL script, declare the PL/SQL package, and then use a function in the package. The error I am getting is that callstmt.execute(); is an invalid SQL statement.

main.java:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

class main
{
  public static void main (String args [])
       throws SQLException, IOException
  {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    String connect = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@vmaddress:1521:xe";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (connect, "user", "pass");

    //Perform setup
    //Load packages, allow output, establish sale database
    //Make sure to run the main script from dbSetup to have fresh data
    CallableStatement callstmt = conn.prepareCall ("@setup.sql");
    callstmt.execute();
    callstmt.close();

    CallableStatement callstmt2 = conn.prepareCall ("{ ? = call salepack.getspname(?) }");
    callstmt2.registerOutParameter (1, Types.VARCHAR);
    int id = 23;    // the id is hard-coded here for simplicity
    callstmt2.setInt(2, id);

    callstmt2.execute();
    String name = callstmt2.getString(1);
    System.out.println ("The salesperson with id of " + id + " is " + name);
    callstmt2.close();
    conn.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears that you have a SQL*Plus script.  If you want to use that, you'd need to invoke the SQL*Plus client.  I suppose you could invoke the SQL*Plus executable from your Java application assuming that the Java application is running on a machine with a full Oracle client install.  But that would be a very odd architecture.  If you need to invoke a SQL*Plus script, that would make more sense as part of an installation process external to you application.  Alternately, it would make more sense to store the code somewhere that the Java application can read one statement at a time.

Comment: Are you trying to roll your own application build process?  Java's probably the wrong language for the task.  Try a scripting language like Groovy.  Alternatively, use one of the existing packages out there, like [FlyWay](http://flywaydb.org/)  (no endorsement intended or implied).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may run setup.sql with below code

```
private static String script_location = "";
private static String file_extension = ".sql";
private static ProcessBuilder processBuilder =null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    File file = new File("C:/sql_folder");
    File [] list_files= file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File f) {
            if (f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(file_extension))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i<list_files.length;i++){
        script_location = "@" + list_files[i].getAbsolutePath();//ORACLE
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sqlplus",        "UserName/Password@database_name", script_location); //ORACLE
        //script_location = "-i" + list_files[i].getAbsolutePath();
        //  processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sqlplus", "-Udeep-Pdumbhead-Spc-de-deep\\sqlexpress-de_com",script_location);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String currentLine = null;
        while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(" "  + currentLine);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and maybe below link will give you some other idea;

[How to display sqlplus result in java?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2354104)